# Trying to use a xamarin app to create a user login for a website

Tags: c#, plugins, authentication, xamarin.forms

I have a cross platform app currently designed using xamarin forms but now need to use this to create a user profile for the user, using the information provided, for a website.

Are there any add ons or plugins for something like square space or wordpress which would allow me to upload a user program via a RESTful api or something along those lines?

Basically what are my options to transfer user data from a cross platform app to a web app so that my user can then log onto the web app and see all their information?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a database that can be accessed by both your web app and your mobile app. There are numerous services that would allow you to do this.

But if your web site is going to be a WordPress site (I have never looked into squarespace) then it already uses a MySql back end for data storage. I would imagine squarespace uses a database of some sort as well. You could then create RESTFul urls on that same server to send and request data and use whatever database system that your website is using. If you don't want to implement your own service code for sending and receiveing data that can be used by both your web app and your mobile app, then you could use some service like Azure, AWS, Apigee, etc. just for the database.